# How do I determine if it is 3.5 minutes later using vbscript?

Tags: datetime, vbscript

How do I determine if it is 3.5 minutes later using vbscript?

```
<%On Error Goto 0

Dim timer, timeNow, timeStart

timeStart = Request.Cookies("timeStart")
'timeNow = time()

If Trim(timeStart) = "" Then
Response.Cookies("timeStart") = Now()
End If

Response.Write "timeStart: " & timeStart    

' if it is past 3 1/2 minutes later
If Now() > timeStart Then
%>
<!-- 'call javascript function? -->
Call Javascript Exit Survey
<%
End If
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If Now() > DateAdd("s", 210, timeStart) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`DateDiff("n",fromDate,toDate,vbMonday)`